# multiple OPENTBS_CHANGE_PICTURE in pptx shows same picture

Tags: opentbs

I'm trying to replace multiple pictures in the same pptx with different images, but all the pictures end up using the same image file.  I've simplified my template as much as possible, and I run the following code:

```
include_once('TinyButStrong/tbs_class.php');
include_once('TinyButStrong/tbs_plugin_opentbs.php');
$TBS = new clsTinyButStrong;
$TBS->Plugin(TBS_INSTALL, OPENTBS_PLUGIN);
$template = "Blank1.pptx";
$TBS->LoadTemplate($template, OPENTBS_ALREADY_UTF8);
$TBS->PlugIn(OPENTBS_CHANGE_PICTURE, '[logo]', 'dir1/image.png');
$TBS->PlugIn(OPENTBS_CHANGE_PICTURE, '[manager1]', 'dir2/image.png');
$TBS->Show(OPENTBS_FILE, 'output.pptx');
```

Both [logo] and [manager1] appear to use the first image; the second image doesn't appear anywhere in the output.

Blank1.pptx: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=91896797071510548344

output.pptx: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=09650184799482515028

I don't know what else to try. :(

Comment: I cannot reproduce your bug. Here is what I've got when running your snippet (thanks a lot for giving the pptx) http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=76823160899872115332 can you simply check your PNG files ?

Comment: I realized something: some of my tests use the same filename for the various images (not logo.png vs photo.png as shown in my sample code), but they are in different folders (ie- different paths).  Perhaps that's making opentbs think they're the same file even though they're not?

Comment: Ah, I see on line 1573, you say "uniqueness by the name of the file, not its full path, this is a weakness" https://github.com/Skrol29/opentbs/blob/master/tbs_plugin_opentbs.php ... if you simply remove basename() from line 1575, will that fix this? (without introducing problems elsewhere)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't heard back from @Skrol29 yet, but I went ahead and removed the basename() call from line 1575 in tbs_plugin_opentbs.php and that fixed the problem I was experiencing.  So far it's working without any negative side effects, so I'm posting this answer for others' reference while awaiting any further feedback from @Skrol29.